# Can we execute C program in Android Studio without using NDK?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-ndk

I'm trying to develop an app that executes c program output. I know that it is possible by using NDK. But I want to execute without NDK. Is it possible?

Comment: Sure. Implement your own Native Development Kit; I hope you have **significant** time to commit to this project. Not sure why you added Java and Kotlin to your question, or how/if it's at all relevant to the "c program output".